# What centralised reference management software should we use?

Tags: bibliography

I am currently searching for a reference management software to be used collaboratively in our research group. Unfortunately, the bigger proprietary software systems (like EndNote and Citavi) don't support synchronisation between different clients. We'd like to use a system which is network based (as in Client-Server or easy synchronisation) and integrates well with MS Word/OpenOffice.org.

So, what kind of software do you use to do your reference management?

Greetings, evnu

P.s. I asked the same question on stackoverflow.com at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656744/what-centralised-reference-management-software-should-we-use (just in case you stumpled over the question there as well)

Comment: For anyone interested: We settled with a simple, but not very powerful, solution: We'll host a central project for citavi on a server, accessible via samba or network drive. Citavi puts a writelock onto the file, so only one person at a time can write the project. That should be sufficient for now.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Zotero (supports sync) or CiteULike (good support for group citations).